# Subprocess The system cannot find the file specified Error

Tags: python, subprocess

I have `subrpocess` function to start a `postgres` table. But I'm getting a file path error

```
filepath = self.get_path(filename)
...

if not append:
# Create the new table itself without adding actual data.
  print "this is the path {}\n\n".format(filepath)
  print "does file exist".format(os.path.isfile(filepath))
  create_table = subprocess.Popen(['shp2pgsql', '-p', '-I',
                                   '-s', str(srid),
                                   '-W', encoding,
                                    filepath, table],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    universal_newlines=True)
```

this is the traceback I'm getting:

```
this is the path C:/Urbansims/inputs\geographies/cities.shp


does file exist? True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loading_data.py", line 117, in <module>
    loader.load_shp_map({value["sql_in"]:"/".join(value["input"].rsplit("/",2)[1:]) for key,value in geo_inputs.iteritems()})
  File "c:\urbansims\libs\spandex\spandex\io.py", line 416, in load_shp_map
    self.load_shp(filename=value, table=table, drop=True)
  File "c:\urbansims\libs\spandex\spandex\io.py", line 369, in load_shp
    universal_newlines=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

the path exist and the os.find.path is returning a True for the location. Why cant the system find the path if it clearly is the correct path to the file?

Comment: Use *shp2pgsql*'s full path. Probably same thing happens when trying to run it from *cmd*.

Comment: I think it's saying it couldn't find `shp2pgsql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `filepath` as an *argument* to the `shp2pgsql` tool that you are trying to launch in a separate process. The error comes from `shp2pgsql` not being found.

Comment: yes `The system cannot find the file specified` comes from the Windows system, not the program itself. Infuriating vague dumb windows message...